# Share .XML configuration files between applications?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

Does anyone have any advice on how i can Use 1 application to write a configuration file, that another application loads and uses?  I'm having a hard time finding where to store this configuration file and allow them both to access it at the same time.

### Example Apps

App That Uses Config.exe
App That Creates/Edits Config.exe

### Config

Settings.Xml

Comment: What about having both projects use a common config that specifies the location of the config that one creates, so they both know where to look?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET configuration files you can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to open a .NET configuration file. Usually you use it to access the configuration settings of the current application, but you can also use the [OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload that takes the path of an exe as parameter to open, modify and save the settings of another application.
In case you want to create a configuration file in a format of your own, you can use any of the XML-APIs that .NET offers to load, modify and save XML files (e.g. [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)).